# How to create an application pool with appcmd?

Tags: iis, iis-7, configuration, azure, appcmd

I have figured out I could associate an existing application pool with an existing site like this:

```
APPCMD.exe set app "sitename/" /applicationPool:"appPoolName"
```

But how do I create my own application pool with the name appPoolName, .NET version 4 and Integrated pipeline prior to this command?

Comment: the slash after "sitename/" is really important, I failed to add that at first and I was struggling, thanks

Comment: I'd add a comment if I had the required 50 rep points - just wanted to update the broken link in the accepted answer - new link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe

should give you everything you need. In particular

`appcmd add apppool /name:appPoolName /managedRuntimeVersion:"v4.0" /managedPipelineMode:"Integrated"`

should do the job.